# How can I get Weekday in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In my table, there is one filed named "Reporting_Date". And I want to get Weekday name of all dates from table. Weekday like sunday, monday. How does it possible in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **DAYNAME(date)**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname

```
mysql> SELECT DAYNAME('2007-02-03');
        -> 'Saturday'

SELECT DAYNAME(Reporting_Date) FROM <table_name> WHERE 1
```

I guess you could model date format according to your requirements.

Comment: Thank You. Have a nice day :)